# Supported opengl version on lenovo 11e laptop?

Tags: opengl

I have this laptop:
http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/thinkpad/11e-series/11e-3rd-gen-intel/?menu-id=thinkpad_11e_3rd_gen_windows

where I have installed Ubuntu. I am trying to determine what version of opengl is supported on the laptop so I run:

```
glxinfo|more
```

which gives:

```
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
    Vendor: Intel Open Source Technology Center (0x8086)
    Device: Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 520 (Skylake GT2)  (0x1916)
    Version: 12.0.3
    Accelerated: yes
    Video memory: 3072MB
    Unified memory: yes
    Preferred profile: core (0x1)
    Max core profile version: 4.3
    Max compat profile version: 3.0
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.1
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 520 (Skylake GT2) 
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 12.0.3
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
    GL_3DFX_texture_compression_FXT1, GL_AMD_conservative_depth, 
    GL_AMD_draw_buffers_blend, GL_AMD_seamless_cubemap_per_texture, 
    GL_AMD_shader_stencil_export, GL_AMD_shader_trinary_minmax,
```

From that it looks like the graphics card in the laptop supports opengl version:

```
 Max core profile version: 4.3
```

But when I run:

```
glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 12.0.3
```

so maybe only version 3.0?

From this website:
https://learnopengl.com/#!Getting-started/OpenGL

seems some pretty significant architectural changes were introduced in version 3.3 so could be great if I can use that.

What of the above output tells me the correct version and can I use opengl 3.3 on this machine?

Seems I have 4.4:

[image]

Comment: Your computer supports OpenGL 4.3. Do your code and set the context to core 4.3. It should work.

Comment: ok from this one: http://antongerdelan.net/opengl/hellotriangle.html mesa drivers only supports up to opengl 3.0 where do I find drivers for my graphics card so I can use 4.3?

Comment: That link is old. Your drivers (Mesa included) currently support ogl 4.3

Comment: ah, so 4.3 supported it is then, great, I am currently following this tutorial http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/introduction-opengl-programming but might be there are better tutorials for 4.3? Yes sidetracking a bit here :-)

Comment: On windows 10 it says 4.4 - see updated post - so seems it depends on OS

Comment: Of course it depends on the OS, the drivers, and what not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't filter the output via `grep`, but read it all.

`glxinfo` reports separately:

- the highest OpenGL Core Profile version available (in your case: 4.3)
- the highest non-Core / Compatibility / < 3.2 OpenGL version available (in your case: 3.0)
- the highest OpenGL ES 1 version available (1.1)
- the highest OpenGL ES 2/3 version available (3.1)

The reason why Core and non-Core are reported separately is because drivers are allowed to not implement the Compatibility profile for OpenGL >= 3.2. That's precisely your case: Core gives you 4.3, non-Core only 3.0.

(Basically, OpenGL made a colossal and gigantic mess around the 3.0 and 3.1 versions. Nobody really talks about them. For mental simplicity, you can split the versioning between 3.2+ Core and pre-3.0. See also [here](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Core_And_Compatibility_in_Contexts)).

Similarly, OpenGL ES 1 and 2/3 are not compatible between each other, so you need to query *both* to figure out what are the respective supported versions. (ES 2 and 3 *are* compatible between them, so they're in just one line).

Comment: Ok so that just made it more confusing :-) So when they talk about 3.3 here:  https://learnopengl.com/#!Getting-started/OpenGL is that Core or Non-Core?I have no clue what ES is so for now I will just ignore that.

Comment: That's post 3.2, so consider it Core.

Comment: That tutorial refers to "modern" OpenGL, which means Core Profile version >=  3.2. OpenGL ES refers to "Embedded System", an API for smart phones.